# how to use an reset button like in the demo of greensock in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to reset my tweens just like the reset button in the Interactive demo – tweening basics field of greensock http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/
In this field you can choose an tween and press the reset button to reset it, I want exactly the same this are my tweens:

```
TweenLite.to(auto, 0.1, {x:241.3, y:372.8});
TweenLite.to(man, 0.1, {x:241.3, y:372.8});
```

can someone help me?

this is how my code looks like:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, einde2);
function einde2(e:Event){
    if(auto.hitTestObject(eindeauto)){
        TweenLite.killTweensOf(auto);
        auto.x = -125.9;
        auto.y = 375.6;

        }}
```

this is the whole code for the object auto:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rijden); // Add the button click

function rijden(e:MouseEvent):void {

     stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rijden); // unplug "rijden" handler
     stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spring); // Add the button click
var randNum:Number;

randNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 5 + 2000);
trace(randNum);
var timer:Timer = new Timer(randNum);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, randGen);

function randGen(e:TimerEvent):void {

var timerObj:Timer = e.target as Timer;
randNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 5 + 2000);
TweenLite.to(auto, 4, {x:666.15, y:375.6});
timerObj.delay = randNum;
}
timer.start();


}
```

Comment: where do you call TweenLite.to(), though? outside of the enter_frame i hope?

Comment: @DodgerThud yes this is called in an stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK) event

Comment: @DodgerThud but it is located in an TimerEvent I will post the whole code

Answer (score 0):

Well, you just set the coordinates of the DisplayObject back to it's original position. Consider the following

```
var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(s);
s.x = 10; //the initial coordinates
s.y = 10;
TweenLite.to(s, 0.1, {x:100, y:100});
```

This code adds a Sprite to the stage at 10,10, then moves it to 100,100 in 0.1 seconds.
now you want to reset it, lets say by clicking on the DisplayObject(in this case the Sprite s).

```
s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    s.x = 10;
    s.y = 10;
}
```

So, once the Sprite is on the stage, it moves to the lower right. When you click it, it instantly moves back to it's original position.

Comment: thanks but if the sprite is back it starts to tween again, but it has to go to that place and go when it is clicked

Comment: can you tell me how I can stop the tween from tweening because the tween keeps going??

Comment: edit your question and show some more code. where do you call the TweenLite methods? Inside of a loop or something?